# Android ListView setOnItemClickListener not working if item has a button with onClick

Tags: android, listview

I'm new in Android development and I don't understand something, even if is a simple thing: I have a ListView that each item contains a textview and a button. When clicked on a button it fires setOnClickListener inside getView method. Also, I have a setOnItemClickListener adapter on this ListView but that method does not fire when the label is clicked. Why is this happening?

UPDATE

This is how the button click fires:

```
ImageButton btnToMap = view.findViewById(R.id.btnToMap);
            btnToMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Coordinates coordinate = MainActivity.coordinates.get(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "coordonata apasata: " + coordinate.latitude + ";"
                            + coordinate.longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: add `focusable = false` and `focusableInTouchMode = false` to button!!

Comment: Why is this happening?

Comment: because, button is gaining the focus of your `row`, which results not triggering `OnItemClick()`

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: Make all the children of your `row_layout` to `focusable=false`, `focusableInTouchMode = false` and add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your parent.

Comment: @Wizard Thanks for your answer. Please add it as a real answer so I can mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159480/discussion-between-wizard-and-dana).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of View focus problem everyone newbie suffers from ;)

Simple solution:

Make **all the children of your `row_layout` to 
`focusable=false`, `focusableInTouchMode = false`** and **add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your parent**.

Answer (score 0):

Use focusable or requestfocus() as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file where you defined your button add:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onClick` method in your Adapter class and check which view was clicked.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button)
            mButtonListener.buttonOnClick();
        else
            mItemListener.itemOnClick();
    }
```

`mButtonListener` and `mItemListener` are listeners passed to Adapter in constructor.

```
private final OnButtonListener mButtonListener;
private final OnItemListener mItemListener;

public MyAdapter(OnButtonListener buttonListener, OnItemListener itemListener) {
    mButtonListener = buttonListener;
    mItemListener = itemListener;

}

public interface OnButtonListener {
    void buttonOnClick();
}

public interface OnItemListener {
    void itemOnClick();
}
```

I used this in my [Inventory App you can find source code here](https://github.com/gbielanski/InventoryApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pl/gbielanski/inventoryapp/InventoryAdapter.java)